# NSPopupButton not working in an NSTableview

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data

I have a program using Core Data, with the columns of an `NSTableView` bound through an `NSArrayController`. This is working with out an issue, table columns populate without issue. I am expanding the table to include an `NSPopupButton` - however something odd happens when the button is added. Just dragging the button in to the column, then running the program without connections or binding to the `Popup`, all the other columns do not populate correctly - they just show the default placeholder text.

Thoughts?

I can get the `NSPopupButton` to populate, but still the other columns only show the default text. If I remove the `NSPopupButton` everything works fine.

Why would the other columns have issues? I tried added a `CheckBox` and had the same issue. I've searched around the net and SO, but have not found an answer.

I would appreciate any thoughts/suggestions.

Thank you in advance.

[EDIT]----

The Table is view-based and `NSTableCellView`.

arrayController:

- Bound to Entity Name
- Parameters, bound to Main Controller; key path:managedObjectContext

TableView:

Columns:

- Value: Bound to arrayController, key path: name, age, etc...

`NSPopupButton`:

Value: Bound to Main Controller, Path: catArrayController.arrangedObjects.name

Main Controller:

IBOutlet: catArrayController
Bound to catArrayController in IB

Comment: Is the table view view-based or `NSCell`-based? If view-based, are the cell views `NSTableCellView`s or are they simply controls like `NSTextField`? Explain what bindings have been set up for the table and/or its columns, with specificity. Is anything logged to the console in the broken case?

Comment: See edits: Also, no errors or info in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a view-based table view, you are intended to bind the table view's Content binding to the array controller. You do **not** bind the columns' Value binding. From [Table View Programming Guide for Mac: Populating a Table View Using Cocoa Bindings](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/PopulatingViewTablesWithBindings/PopulatingView-TablesWithBindings.html):

> **Note:** In an `NSView`-based table, you bind the table view’s content to the array controller’s `arrangedObjects`. This differs from the technique you use if you’re working with an `NSCell`-based table.

That binding causes each cell view to have its `objectValue` property set to the object corresponding to the row, if it has such a property. Note that the cell views don't get a column-specific value. All of the cells of a row get the same value.

Since your cell views are `NSTableCellView`s, they have an `objectValue` property. Then, the subviews of the cell view should have their Value binding bound to the cell view with a key path running through `objectValue` to the specific property (name, age, etc.).

In the old `NSCell`-based table views, you would typically not bind the Content (or Selection Indexes or Sort Descriptors) bindings of the table view itself at design time. You would bind the table columns as you have done. At run time, the table view would automatically establish bindings for its own Content, Selection Indexes, and Sort Descriptors based on the bindings of its columns. I suspect some version of this behavior was happening in your app which was allowing things to kind of work. However, I suspect that adding the new column broke that system. It was a fluke that it was working for the view-based table view in the first place, so was inherently fragile.

Comment: Setting it up this way does work - thank you. I am new and have been reading the book from Aaron Hillegass in which he does bind the columns value binding - which I now find interesting. If you know why, could you please send me a PM - thanks again.

Comment: I can only guess that that edition of the book predates the existence of view-based table views. So, it would have been `NSCell`-based but would not have known to specifically mention that fact, since that was the only kind. And you're welcome.